# jQuery.get fails inside jQuery submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've used `$.get` successfully in the past, but cannot make it work inside a jQuery submit event.  According to the jQuery documentation, the submit event intercepts a form's submit event and prevents the HTML form action from happening as long as you return false.  I've verified this works.  In the code below, I use `$.get` twice (once before the event handler and then inside it).  It works great in the first case, but fails inside the submit event.

test.php code:

```
<?php
$handle = $_GET['handle'];
echo($handle);
?>
```

client.php code:

```
<div>
<form id="message_box_form" style="height:100px;width:300px" method="get" action="../phpDB/test.php">
    <textarea id="message_box" style="height:30px;width:250px;" type="text" name="messagecontent"></textarea>
    <input id="share_button" name="share_button" type="submit" value="Share" />     
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.get("../phpDB/test.php",{handle:'nightstalker'}, function(data){              
        alert(data);    // This works fine  
    });

    $('#message_box_form').submit( function() {
        alert('jQuery submit handler called');   //This happens
        $.get("../phpDB/test.php",{handle:'rodbender'}, function(data){  
            alert(data);    // This NEVER happens
            return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return false;` is in wrong place:

```
$('#message_box_form').submit( function() {
    alert('jQuery submit handler called');   //This happens
    $.get("../phpDB/test.php",{handle:'rodbender'}, function(data){  
        alert(data);    
    });
    return false; // should in the callback of submit.
});
```

Or you could use `e.preventDefault();`:

```
$('#message_box_form').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('jQuery submit handler called');   //This happens
    $.get("../phpDB/test.php",{handle:'rodbender'}, function(data){  
        alert(data);    
    });
});
```